# Overriding: same onDraw for many Views (Button, TextView) elements

Tags: java, android

I need to draw custom borders in android to all of the views on my screen. Every view will have different parameters. To do this, I thought about making new `CustomBotton`, `CustomTextView` etc. classes and redefine their `onDraw()` methods. But the methods will contain the same code, so it's not nice to

1. make new classes for those Views and
2. rewrite the same `onDraw()` method with the same code.

Is there a more elegant/faster way to do this?

Comment: The elegant way, I think, is use of _Strategy pattern_

Comment: It's just using an Interface... bad help

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this for simple and fast solution (Doing things quick always has a performance trade off).

1. Dont deal with onDraw for anyview.
2. Make a single class extending LinearLayout.

   2.1 Set Background of this Linearlayout as color of your border.

   ```
   2.1.1 - More better read border color attribute from xml at runtime.
   ```

   2.2 Set its padding as width of your border.

   2.3 Set its width and height as wrap_content and wrap_content respectively.
3. Add single view to this LinearLayout. Either programatically or via xml.

   ```
   <com.example.BorderLinearLayout >

       <ImageView /> // or whatever. But a single view or viewgroup only

   </com.example.BorderLinearLayout>
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems to be nice, unless Android guidelines suggests to use as less Layouts as possible on every Activity to get the best performance. I'll try this anyway ;)